# When Selecting checkbox another element text changes in Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have an element and when I click on Element1 another elements text adds up a number "1". How do I verify it that when I click on element a number adds up. Clicks on Element1, Element2, Element3, and Apples number adds up. How would you write a script in a method. Page oBjects = Viva_element = element. Apple_Image = text for apple. Is this correct way to do it.

```
    Element1.     Apples 1
    Element2.     Apples 2 
    Element3      Apples 3
```

---

```
  public void selectingelements() {

    for(int index = 0; index < Viva_element.size(); index ++) {
        Viva_element.get(0).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples (1)");
        APList.get(1).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples (2)");
        APList.get(2).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples (3)");
        APList.get(3).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples (4)");


}
```

Comment: What you want to verify here when you click on Element1 ,  your expected result is Apple or Apple 1 . Any challenge you are facing in above mentioned code?

Comment: Apple 1. I want to know if its correct or is there another way to do it shorter way. When I click element 1 the other element should be Apple 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Following code will full fill your current requirement , please try once :

public void selectingelements() {

    for(int index = 1; index < Viva_element.size(); index ++) {
        Viva_element.get(index-1).click();
        Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples " + index);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have (index+1) in quotes it will not count up automatically correct.

Comment: Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples " + index+1);
FAILED: test
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [Apples 01] but found [Apples (1)]

Comment: You are expecting Apple 01 or Apple 1 as Apple 1 should work fine with this.

Comment: if you do index + 1 = it gives me Apple 01 answer. I need Apple 1 answer.

Comment: Also After first checkbox it shuts down do you know why  is it something wrong with timing.

Comment: I meant when it clicks first checkbox it shuts down the app and says pass. Test Complete.

Comment: Please try this code as in previous code index was adding in real value for(int index = 1; index <= Viva_element.size(); index ++) {
            Viva_element.get(index-1).click();
            Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples " + index);
        }

Comment: Another alternative : 
for(int index = 0; index < Viva_element.size(); index ++)
{
 Viva_element.get(index).click();
 Assert.assertEquals(Apple_Image.getText(), "Apples " +(index+1)); 
}

Comment: When I run it. compares first checkbox and says program complete pass but there are 5 checkboxes to compare? Do you know why?

Comment: To get Viva_element , your are using findElement or findElements , what is the size of your Viva_element, can you print and check.

Comment: I'm using page object by id.

Comment: Did you check size of your viva_element, how many elements are there in this array.

Comment: I have 3 elements= 0,1,2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419675/i-get-an-error-when-trying-to-sort-first-name-alphabetically-and-sort-last-name. Could you please help with this one.