# I get an error when trying to sort first name alphabetically and sort last name alphabetically in Appium from elements names

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have 3 elements and they have 3 names with last names its a button. I need to figure out how to check if they sorted by first name and then by last name.Page object for elements is ListV_Sorted. I think I just sorted by first name elements. 0 element = Jack Daniels, 1 element = John Fera, 2 element = Mike Durov. ListV is a page object for the elements. It says expected true but found false.

//Verifies if APs Names Sorted Alphabetically 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sortingOrder() {

```
      Log.log(driver).info("About to Alphebetically Sort");
      List<MobileElement> products_MobileElements = new LinkedList<MobileElement>();
      products_MobileElements = (List<MobileElement>) TicketPassesNames;
      LinkedList<String> product_names =  new LinkedList<String>();

      for(int i=0;i<products_MobileElements.size();i++){

          String s = products_MobileElements.get(i).getAttribute("checked");
          String[] tokens = s.split(""); 
          String firstName = "";
          String lastName = "";
          if(tokens.length > 0) {
              firstName = tokens[0];
              lastName = tokens[tokens.length -1];
              product_names.add(s);
              product_names.add(firstName);
              product_names.add(lastName);

          }
      }
      boolean result = checkAlphabeticalOrder(product_names);

      Assert.assertEquals(checkAlphabeticalOrder(product_names), true);
        Log.log(driver).info("Tickest Passes names are in alphabetical order.");
        System.out.println(result);


    }


      //Method takes a String to Sort AlphabeticalLy
      public static boolean checkAlphabeticalOrder(LinkedList<String> product_names){

            String previous = ""; // empty string

            for (final String current: product_names) {
                if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
                    return false;
                previous = current;
            }

            return true;

            }
```

Comment: Can you put System.out.println(current +" "+ previous ) to check what is printing it will help in debugging

Comment: current and previous give me false statements. How come it passes the test.

Comment: for (final String current : product_names) {
   if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
    return false;
   previous = current;
   System.out.println(current);
   System.out.println(previous);
  }

  return true;